# Android cursor fetch understanding

Tags: android, cursor

I would like to understand a line in a piece of code I saw:

```
public Cursor fetchMessageByMessageId(String msgId) {
    Cursor mCursor =

    mDb.query(true, DATABASE_MESSAGES_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_CONVERSATION_ID, KEY_MSG_ID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY,
            KEY_IS_REPLY, KEY_MEDIA_LOC, KEY_URL, KEY_TIMESTAMP },
            KEY_MSG_ID + "='" + msgId + "'", null, null, null, null, null);
    **if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }**
    return mCursor;
}
```

The following lines of code in between **

Is this line necessary? I spent 2 hours debugging today finding out why my data was missing when I called something like

```
while(mCursor.moveTonext())
```

use the cursor to grab some data and ended up missing the first data always. So I looked at my other parts of the code and realised that I dumped the whole cursor into the adapter so the bold line above had no effect whatsoever. After removing those lines of code everything was good!

So in short, if I just want a cursor with 1 result or many, is it necessary to call the bold statement above? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you get a set of row when you call `query()`. Initially the cursor will be pointing to nothing. If you call `mCursor.moveToNext()` or `mCursor.moveToFirst()`, then you will want to point the the first row. Additional calls to `mCursor.moveToNext()` will move the cursor to next tuple.
In short, only call `mCursor.moveToNext()` when you need to get information from next row (if it exists).

Comment: Initially cursor won't be pointing to the first row. It will do this only after calling `moveToFirst()` or `moveToNext()`